# How to set focus on button while button is disabled in winform c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, controls

I want to set the focus in the button when a button is disabled in the windows form application.

Is there any way to achieve this goal?

Background:

I am making an application that can be used by a blind person so when the button is enabled then on focus screen reader will read of button content but when a button is disabled then not possible to read by screen reader because of the button can not be focused on disabled mode

Comment: The whole point of disabling a control is to prevent it from gaining focus.  That's the fundamental feature.

Comment: Well you can try to call `.Focus()` on the button. Perhaps in a click handler - although i'm not sure if that fires when the button is disabled.

Comment: @RaceRalph agreed with your point but I want to make a button like read-only for accessibility.

Comment: " I want to make a button like read-only for accessibility" I find this very confusing. can you elaborate?

Comment: .Focus() will not work if a control is disabled.  This is by design.

Comment: @VijayMandanka Can you try to unbound and bound click event rather than make it disable, Is it helpful to you?

Comment: @MongZhu I am making an application that can be used by a blind person so when the button is enabled then on focus screen reader will read of button content but when a button is disabled then not possible to read by screen reader because of the button can not be focused on disabled mode.

Comment: why not add this additional information : "disabled" to the text of the button while you unhook the event. This way the reader can even provide this intormation to the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom control and create one propriety into a custom control. using that property to check **OnClick** need to fire or not.

For Example:

```
   public class buttonReadonly: Button
   {
       private bool _isReadOnly = false;

       public bool isReadOnly
       {
           get
           {
               return _isReadOnly;
           }
           set
           {
               _isReadOnly = value;
           }
       }

       protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
       {
           if (!isReadOnly)
           {
               base.OnClick(e);
           }
       }
       
   }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try to add and remove the event of click by below code rather than enable and disable the button in C#.

For remove click event

```
button.Click -= button_Click;
```

For add click event

```
button.Click += button_Click;
```

For reference, you can refer to the below link.

[How to subscribe to and unsubscribe from events (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/how-to-subscribe-to-and-unsubscribe-from-events)